# Is there a way to get corresponding values of indexes within keys in a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, indexing

So let's say I have a dictionary for object detections:

```
dict = {'x1y1coords': [(124, 101), (22, 104)], 'objecttype': [1, 2]}
```

is there a way that I can easily extract the first value under the list which is under the key value x1y1coords? Just to show what I have in mind:

```
print((dict['x1y1coords'])[0])
```

something like this (just to further explain what I had in mind). It's like getting the index of a key index of a dictionary.

And also, it is quite related to this topic, so I don't think I need to create another question (but you can advise me if you think this question needs to be discussed as another problem), I would also like to compare the values of that [x] from ['x1y1coords] to the values of [x] from ['objecttype']. By using my sample code (the one within the print function):

```
if (dict['objecttype'])[x] == 2:
     p1, p2 = (dict['objecttype'])[x]
```

Comment: Is this a TensorFlow(or cv2 ) question ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can absolutely do exactly that:

```
>>> d = {'x1y1coords': [(124, 101), (22, 104)], 'objecttype': [1, 2]}
>>> d['x1y1coords']
[(124, 101), (22, 104)]
>>> d['x1y1coords'][0]
(124, 101)
```

If you wanted to assign those values to `x` and `y` you could do:

```
>>> x, y = d['x1y1coords'][0]
>>> x
124
>>> y
101
```

If you wanted to do something with *all* the `x, y` values in the list, instead of just the first one (`[0]`) you might use a `for` loop:

```
>>> for x, y in d['x1y1coords']:
...     print(f"x: {x}\ty: {y}")
...
x: 124  y: 101
x: 22   y: 104
```